# Why does having EOF in parser rules influence the lexer in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar, lexer

Start with simple grammar:

```
grammar Simple;

file  : lines ;
lines : (ID | INT | STRING)+ '\r'? '\n';

ID       : [a-zA-Z_]*;
INT      : [0-9]*;
STRING   : '"' ~["\r\n]* '"';
COMMA    : ',';
WS       : [ \t\f]+ -> skip ;
```

**Example #1 | Valid Input**

```
aaa
999

[@0,0:2='aaa',<3>,1:0]
[@1,3:3='\n',<2>,1:3]
[@2,4:6='999',<4>,2:0]
```

**Example #2 | Invalid Input**

Added some commas to the input without changing parser rules but surprisingly this doesn't raise any errors, also don't understand why the lexer stops tokenizing at `999` instead of reading to the end of file.

```
   aaa
   999
   777,rrr
   fff,456,iom

   [@0,0:2='aaa',<3>,1:0]
   [@1,3:3='\n',<2>,1:3]
   [@2,4:6='999',<4>,2:0]
```

**Example #3 | Parser Adjustments**

Added 'EOF' to the start rule:

```
file  : lines EOF ;
```

Now the lexer reads to the end, and the parser raises the expected error:

```
   aaa
   999
   777,rrr
   fff,456,iom

   [@0,0:2='aaa',<3>,1:0]
   [@1,3:3='\n',<2>,1:3]
   [@2,4:6='999',<4>,2:0]
   [@3,7:7='\n',<2>,2:3]
   [@4,8:10='777',<4>,3:0]
   [@5,11:11=',',<6>,3:3]
   [@6,12:14='rrr',<3>,3:4]
   [@7,15:15='\n',<2>,3:7]
   [@8,16:18='fff',<3>,4:0]
   [@9,19:19=',',<6>,4:3]
   [@10,20:22='456',<4>,4:4]
   [@11,23:23=',',<6>,4:7]
   [@12,24:26='iom',<3>,4:8]
   [@13,27:27='\n',<2>,4:11]
   [@14,28:27='<EOF>',<-1>,5:0]

   [2:0 | [@2,4:6='999',<4>,2:0] | why? mismatched input '999' expecting <EOF>]
```

**Questions**

Regarding *Example #2*...

1. why did the parser not raise any errors?
2. why did the lexer stop tokenizing at `999` instead of reading to the end of file?
3. My understanding was the lexer and parser are independent and do not communicate in ANTLR4, so how did the lexer know to stop reading at the same location where the parser raised errors in Example #3?

Comment: (1 and 2): In the usual use case, an EOF-terminated start rule forces the parser to read to the end of input and report any errors. Otherwise, it stops at the point of error. It's a "feature" for parsing isolated parts of the input. (3): The parser calls the lexer via "lexer.NextToken()". The parser does have a "context state" that could be accessed by the lexer when NextToken() is called. But the parser also computes a set of possible parse states in AdaptivePredict(). That is cannot be accessed by the lexer in NextToken(). In this regard, the lexer is "independent" from the parser.

Comment: If you consider posting your comment as an answer I'll accept it, just hope you can elaborate on your points.